# Self referencing generic member in struct

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I need to broaden my understanding of how structs are compiled when using generics.

I have the following code, which works

```
public struct TestStruct
{
    public GenericStruct<SecondTestStruct> Header;
    public int TestValue;
}

public struct GenericStruct<T>
{
    public int MessageSize => System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
}

public struct SecondTestStruct
{
    public int TestValue;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestStruct test = new TestStruct();
    Console.WriteLine($"Size of test is: {test.Header.MessageSize}");

}
```

This prints 'Size of test is: 4'

However, if I change TestStruct to attempt to provide its own size:

```
public struct TestStruct
{
    public GenericStruct<TestStruct> Header;
    public int TestValue;
}
```

I get a runtime error: `System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'TestStructGenerics.TestStruct' from assembly.`

I'm guessing it has to do with the compiler being unable to create the struct compile time. Or perhaps a problem with circular references when handling the generic resolution.

**EDIT:**

I just realized that I can achieve what I want by changing the second case to:

```
public struct TestStruct
{
    public GenericStruct<TestStruct> Header => new GenericStruct<TestStruct>();
    public int TestValue;
}
```

Comment: The problem is what you intend this to do. Your struct contains another struct with a generic type T that is the first struct that contains another struct with a generic type T that is the first struct that contains another struct with a generic type T that is the first struct that contains another str... Do you see where this is heading? You've created a compile-time recursive type definition. The compiler could've been smart enough to detect this but apparently not, but either way, *what does it mean*?

Comment: That recursive definition could never work because it makes no sense.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's pretty much what I thought. I would have thought it would have provided me with a compile time error, but apparently not.

Comment: Recursiveness by itself is not a sufficient explanation, because changing either `TestStruct` or `GenericStruct` to be a `class` removes the problematic behavior. It's something peculiar to how generic arguments are handled in structs.

Answer (score 2):

According to Eric Lippert's comments in [this Roslyn issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10126), it is unclear whether this problem is a CLR type loader limitation or whether programs of this sort are invalid, and, if they are invalid, whether the C# compiler should detect it and emit an error. Practically, it appears that, until the authorities decide, we have to avoid type loops between structs regardless of the mode that introduces dependence - instance field (that's never going to work because the struct would be infinite size), static field, implemented generic interface, or generic argument. One can break these struct type loops at compile time by changing some struct in the loop to a class, or at run time by going through `object` or interface and casting.

See also the [corresponding CLR issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/4049).

Comment: Interesting to see that I wasn't totally off point when struggling with this issue