# Why does having a struct P with a generic struct field with type argument P cause a TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, generics, struct, language-lawyer

The following code compiles without warnings or errors, but causes a `TypeLoadException` exception:

```
public struct GuidFor<T>
{
}

public struct Person
{
    public GuidFor<Person> Id;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person p;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when `Person` is a struct and has a field that is a generic struct and uses `Person` as its type argument.

Why does this pattern cause a runtime error? If this wasn't allowed I would expect it to be a compile time error not a runtime error. The equivalent code in C++ works fine and is often useful.

I'm running this code on Windows 10, .NET Core 3.0.100.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if, as an optimization, the system tries to compute the size of each generic type argument before asking how big a specific instance of a generic is - but it needs to know the size of a `GuidFor<Person>` before it can compute the size of a `Person`.

Comment: The concepts of `struct` in C# and C++ are also quite different, so it's tricky to imagine what the "equivalent code" would be in C++.

Comment: After decompilation, the type `GuidFor<T>` has an extra `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 1)]` on it, probably generated by the compiler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self referencing generic member in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995260/self-referencing-generic-member-in-struct) There is also two GitHub issues for that, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/4049) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10126)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes! Thank you for finding this. I've marked this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This is how I would write the same code in C++. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c028a790b273369

Answer (score 0):

This is CLR problem by design. In order to load  struct `Person`CLR needs to load all it's members. So when CLR tries to load `GuidFor<Person> Id` it needs to load `Person` first. And we have a cycle.

CLR undertands this and throw an exception.

Comment: Why is this problem inherent to structs and doesn't come with classes though?

Comment: I suppose it's because structs are Value types and  created on the stack. So all struct fields must be initialized. Security purpouse I think.